# Jsoup text() versus HTML element .innerText()

Tags: javascript, html, jsoup

I am trying to extract text out of an HTML element in jSoup just exactly as the innerText attribute is shown in my browser.

But there is some difference in the two in terms of spacing/newlines.

Here is the element I am trying to extract text out of :

```
<td headers="header2">







                                        ATM<br>

                                        29JUN15 CASHNET 11:13:17<br>

                                        A96013498<br>

                                        ATM<br>


                                    </td>
```

I just copied the element from browser inspect tool.

While this element's innerText from console gives me this :

```
"ATM
29JUN15 CASHNET 11:13:17
A96013498
ATM
"
```

However I am trying to extract the same through Jsoup. This is my code to replace all the `<br>` with `"\n"` and extract text out of the cellEle which is my same HTML element.

```
cellEle //my html element
cellEle.select("br").append("\\n");
cellEle.select("p").append("\\n\\n");
String text = cellEle.html().replace("\\n", "\n");
text = text.replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");
text = text.trim();
String returnText = Jsoup.clean(text, "",Whitelist.none(),new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
```

But this is returning me the same element's text like this :

```
"ATM
 29JUN15 CASHNET 11:13:17
 A96013498
 ATM"
```

Observe the extra space after each line, how do I change this. I would want the output to be exactly as same as the innerText() in the browser console.

Comment: console output is optimized for display output, which is quite different from actual HTML source codes.

Comment: but it won't miss the spaces right ?